# How to generate a thumbnail of video from external storage in react native

Tags: react-native, thumbnails

I tried

- react-native-create-thumbnail
- react-native-thumbnail
- react-native-thumbnail-video
- ffmpeg-kit-react-native

for generating thumbnails, but nothing works. My video file path is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.recordvideo/files/MyApp/Videos/VID_150323_2123411.mp4
```

and file exist. I'm using `react-native-fs` for retrieving video files.

Kindly tell me a correct and clear cut method of generating thumbnail.